# Analyzing of ESS survey, filter and select

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to analyze an ESS survey. I need to put the data in right format (right now it should be only numeric but I need to change it), then filter a country and select a characteristic called "basinc".

Right now my script looks like this and I'm stuck, could somebody please help me?

```
ESS8 <- read.csv("ESS8_num.csv", header = FALSE) 

View(ESS8)

install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

install.packages("foreign")
library(foreign)
```

I tried to run this, but it shows:

```
"Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = cntry == "LT"`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'cntry' not found"

LT <- ESS8%>%
  filter(cntry=="LT")%>%
  select(basinc)
```

I also tried this:

```
LT <- ESS8%>%
  filter(cntry=="LT")%>%
  select(basinc)
```

but it showed me:

```
"Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = cntry == "LT"`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'cntry' not found"
```

Comment: Run `names(ESS8)` to see the variable names in that data frame. As per the error,there is no variable named `cntry`.

Comment: Welcome. Use a minimal data set here for reproduction